# Connection string not found ASP MVC 4 n-tier trying to get SimpleMembership to work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, n-tier-architecture

Okay, So I've been breaking my neck trying to get this SimpleMembership crap to work.  I want to have a DataAccess layer, and I'm trying to get it to perform the SimpleMembership duties. I think I'm getting close, but now my InitializeDatabaseConnection won't find my connection string.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace ElectricCrew.DataAccess
{
public class SimpleMembership
{
    public static void Register(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ECEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UserName, Password);

        WebSecurity.Login(UserName, Password);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the App.config from the DataAccess Layer

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ECEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DefaultConnection.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Sorry for the poor formatting.  My computer won't paste it properly.

Here is what my dataaccess layer looks like
[image]

please halp

Comment: And the SimpleMembership class I wrote is in the DataAccess project / layer

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your connection string has (`& quot;`) where there should be a (") quote in 2 places? Sorry about the formatting I'm new to StackO.